# How do I use a Telerik Grid with a partial page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have an ASP.NET MVC project. One of my pages has an input form on top and a partial page below it for results. The partial page uses a Telerik Grid. Everything works fine if I dont use paging. However with paging turned on I can't get the grid to update.

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "can't get the grid to update"? Do you get errors?

Comment: Could you post code on how the main page and partial page look like and also what exception you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Telerik Grid with partial views, in the following way:

Action (on "MyController"):

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _GetDataForGrid()
{
  return View(new GridModel
  {
    Data = GetMyViewModelList() // IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
  });
}
```

(Partial)View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MyViewModel>>" %>

<%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(x => x.Id))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
            // ...
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
            .Select("_GetDataForGrid", "MyController"))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
%>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does your page calling the partial view contain the script telerik.grid.js? There have been cases where it needs to be included in the partial view as well.

Your ScriptRegistrar on the page should include

ASPX Engine

```
<% Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group
   .Add("telerik.common.min.js")
   .Add("telerik.grid.min.js")
   .Add("telerik.calendar.min.js")
   .Add("telerik.datepicker.min.js")
   .Add("telerik.grid.filtering.js")); 
%>
```

RAZOR Engine

```
@( Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group
       .Add("telerik.common.min.js")
       .Add("telerik.grid.min.js")
       .Add("telerik.calendar.min.js")
       .Add("telerik.datepicker.min.js")
       .Add("telerik.grid.filtering.js")); 
)
```